# strange result scraping a web with python and beautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new in the world of scraping and python. I have this code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

#page = requests.get('https://www.amazon.es/s?i=computers&bbn=937925031&rh=n%3A937925031%2Cp_36%3A6000-45000%2Cp_n_feature_two_browse-bin%3A12783798031%7C12783804031%2Cp_72%3A831280031%2Cp_89%3AAMD%2Cp_n_condition-type%3A15144009031&s=relevancerank&dc&hidden-keywords=AMD&pf_rd_i=937912031&pf_rd_m=A1AT7YVPFBWXBL&pf_rd_p=df2457c3-6814-4d25-b8d4-2c8634f3b639%2Cdf2457c3-6814-4d25-b8d4-2c8634f3b639&pf_rd_r=5QVCN0DS2Q82FPH17RH1%2C5QVCN0DS2Q82FPH17RH1&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-leftnav&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1609806932&rnid=15144007031&ref=sr_nr_p_n_condition-type_1',headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
page = requests.get('https://www.amazon.es/s?i=computers&bbn=937924031&rh=n%3A937924031%2Cp_n_feature_two_browse-bin%3A12783798031%7C12783804031%2Cp_72%3A831280031%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_two_browse-bin%3A4700044031%2Cp_n_condition-type%3A15144009031%2Cp_n_availability%3A831279031&dc&qid=1609807162&rnid=831270031&ref=sr_nr_p_n_availability_2',headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
print(page.status_code)
# page = [
#     ]

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
#print(soup)
product = soup.find(class_='s-main-slot s-result-list s-search-results sg-row')
#print(product)
items = product.find_all(class_='a-section a-spacing-medium') #a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small
print(items[0])

# print(items[0].find(class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal').get_text())
# print(items[0].find(class_ = 'a-price-whole').get_text())
# print(items[0].find(class_ = 'a-size-base').get_text())
# print(items[0].find(class_ = 'a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4-5 aok-align-bottom').get_text())

product_name = [item.find(class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal').get_text() if item.find(class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal') != None else None for item in items]
price = [item.find(class_ = 'a-price-whole').get_text() if item.find(class_ = 'a-price-whole') != None else None for item in items]
# availability = [item.find(class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-inmediata cy-product-availability-date').get_text() for item in items]
rating = [item.find(class_ = 'a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4-5 aok-align-bottom').get_text()  if item.find(class_ = 'a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4-5 aok-align-bottom') != None else None for item in items]
opinion = [item.find(class_ = 'a-size-base').get_text()  if item.find(class_ = 'a-size-base') != None else None for item in items]

# # print(product_name)
# # print(price)
# # print(availability)
# # print(rating)
# # print(opinion)

store = 'Amazon'
extraction_date = datetime.datetime.now()
df = pd.DataFrame (
    {
        'product_name' : product_name,
        'price' : price,
        # 'availability' : availability,
        'rating' : rating,
        'opinion' : opinion,
        'store' : store,
        'date_extraction' : extraction_date,
    })

# # site = ‘mysite’
path = "C:\\PriceTracking\\amazon\\"
# now = datetime.datetime.now()
mydate = extraction_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
mytime = extraction_date.strftime('%H%M%S')
filename = path+store+'_'+mydate+'_'+mytime+".csv"

#df.to_csv(filename)

print(df)
```

Using the page commented always returned the same result but with the second page sometimes it returns the product_name correctly and others it returns none.

I'm sure I'm missing something but no idea where to find the the issue.

By the way, the script only return 24 of 85 results, is there an easy way to extract the products remaining?

Thanks all and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue

Before

```
product_name = [item.find(class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal').get_text() if item.find(class_ = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal') != None else None for item in items]
price = [item.find(class_ = 'a-price-whole').get_text() if item.find(class_ = 'a-price-whole') != None else None for item in items]
# availability = [item.find(class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-inmediata cy-product-availability-date').get_text() for item in items]
rating = [item.find(class_ = 'a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4-5 aok-align-bottom').get_text()  if item.find(class_ = 'a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4-5 aok-align-bottom') != None else None for item in items]
opinion = [item.find(class_ = 'a-size-base').get_text()  if item.find(class_ = 'a-size-base') != None else None for item in items]
```

After

```
product_name = [item.find('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal a-text-normal'}).text.strip() if item.find('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal a-text-normal'}) != None else None for item in items]
price = [item.find('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'}).get_text() if item.find('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'}) != None else None for item in items]
# availability = [item.find(class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-inmediata cy-product-availability-date').get_text() for item in items]
rating = [item.find('span', {'class': 'a-icon-alt'}).text.strip()  if item.find('span', {'class': 'a-icon-alt'}).text.strip() != None else None for item in items]
reviews = [item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base'}).text.strip()  if item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base'}).text.strip() != None else None for item in items]
```

Now I haven´t any None inside product_name field.

Regards